# Create Google Maps screenshots at regular intervals

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, screenshot

### Background

People are concerned that building a pipeline to the West Coast of Canada will increase the number of oil tankers, thus increasing the probability of a major oil spill, thereby creating an environmental catastrophe.

The [AIS Live Ships Map](http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/) website captures real-time Marine Traffic updates using a Google Maps interface. While it is possible to obtain data from an [AIS data feed](http://www.aishub.net/), often the feeds are either [pay-for-use](http://www.aislive.com/dataservices.html#live), or otherwise encumbered with license restrictions.

### Problem

The AIS Live Ships website presents a map in the browser:

[image: Google Maps Screenshot]

The map above has had its location interactively changed to focus on the area in question: the northern straight of Vancouver Island.

### Question

How would you create a service that captures the map every 30 minutes and that could run, with neither user-intervention nor a significant memory footprint, for a few years?

#### Idea #1

1. Create a virtual machine.
2. Install and run a light-weight browser.
3. Use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) to take captures at regular intervals.

#### Idea #2

Use Python's [Ghost Webkit](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to automate the captures.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also considering using [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) (X virtual framebuffer). This has the advantage of being lighter-weight than running a virtual machine, as well as only depending on pretty vanilla software packages.

Searching the web for "xvfb screenshot" should turn up various links on how you might do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look how [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) did it.

It's a website that lets you create screenshots of websites and they're open-source. I would imagine some useful information can be pulled from [their source](http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/).